Who are the Green Lanterns in the 2024 M.D. "Doc" Bright DC Comics tribute?
I recently came across this tribute by DC Comics, honoring the late comic book artist M.D. "Doc" Bright (1955-2024). The piece features a lineup of Green Lanterns, and while I recognized a few familiar faces, there are a few I'm not too sure about. I did a bit of googling, but I still need some help identifying a few of these Lanterns.

The Green Lantern lineup, from left to right, top row to bottom row:

A blond-haired Lantern with a yellow eye patch and part of one arm in yellow
A bald Lantern with a green nose guard (that's how I'll refer to that nose thingy)
A hooded Lantern who also sports a nose guard
G'nort, the red dog Lantern (if I'm not mistaken)
A crystalline Lantern with a mohawk hairstyle (likely Chaselon)
A Lantern who is a black man (John Stewart, if I'm not mistaken)
Hal Jordan
A Lantern with long ears and what seems to be a beak (probably Tomar-Re)
A one-eyed Lantern who looks like a Minion from Despicable Me, but with long hair, six arms, and six legs
Kilowog, the muscular Lantern
A woman Lantern with purple hair and black highlights
A purple mushroom Lantern (could this be Amanita, although the color doesn't quite match the DC Database wiki image)

Can anyone confirm the identities of these Green Lanterns?

What do you mean by "green nose guard".  Those green things on the faces look like Hal Jordan's little green mask.

@M.A.Golding The green thingy on their nose. I'm not sure if it can be called a mask because it doesn't hide their faces.

These Green Lanterns all appeared in Green Lantern Vol. 3 in the early '90s, such as Green Lantern Vol. 3 #34 & 35, for example, both of which were pencilled by the late Mark D. Bright.


Green Lantern Vol. 3 #35 (January, 1993)

Their names are as follows...


A blond-haired Lantern with a yellow eye patch and part of one arm in yellow



Kreon



A bald Lantern with a green nose guard (that's how I'll refer to that nose thingy)



Aa



A hooded Lantern who also sports a nose guard



Brik



G'nort, the red dog Lantern (if I'm not mistaken)



G'nort



A crystalline Lantern with a mohawk hairstyle (likely Chaselon)



Chaselon



A Lantern who is a black man (John Stewart, if I'm not mistaken)



John Stewart



Hal Jordan



Hal Jordan



A Lantern with long ears and what seems to be a beak (probably Tomar-Re)



Tomar-Tu



A one-eyed Lantern who looks like a Minion from Despicable Me, but with long hair, six arms, and six legs



Larvox



Kilowog, the muscular Lantern



Kilowog



A woman Lantern with purple hair and black highlights



Boodikka



A purple mushroom Lantern (could this be Amanita, although the color doesn't quite match the DC Database wiki image)



Amanita

